# Regular expression to check IP

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if an IP address is between 172.16.0.0 and 172.31.255.255

What I tried is this:

```
Pattern address = Pattern.compile("172.[16-31].[0-255].[0-255]");
```

But it doesn't work, the compiler throws an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 8
172.[16-31].[0-255].[0-255]
        ^
```

Since it's an exercise it has to be done with regular expressions.

Comment: You need to read a regexp tutorial to understand how `[]` works. It doesn't do numeric range comparison, it's for matching single characters.

Comment: `[16-31]` means to match a single character that's either `1` or in the range from `6` to `3` (which doesn't make sense because a range has to be low-to-high).

Comment: To match a number from 16 to 31 it should be `(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])`.

Comment: While you can do this with a regexp, I don't think it's the best way. Split the address up into numbers, and then just check their ranges with numeric comparisons.

Comment: You're using a hammer to crack a nut. This is fundamentally a numeric problem, not a string/regular expression problem.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out with the solution you gave as. Sadly it's an exercise I have to do it with regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

One option here would be to split the IP address on period and then check to make sure each component is within the ranges you want:

```
public boolean isIpValid(String input) {
    String[] parts = input.split("\\.");
    int c1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int c2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    int c3 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
    int c4 = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);

    if (c1 == 172 &&
        c2 >= 16 && c2 <= 31 &&
        c3 >= 0 &&  c3 <= 255 &&
        c4 >= 0 &&  c4 <= 255) {
        System.out.println("IP address is valid.");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("IP address is not valid.");
        return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see the point that this is easier but since it's an exercise I have to do it with regex.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your regex does not work is that the character group `[16-31]` means

> "character `1`, any character between `6` and `3`, or character `1`"

This is definitely not what you wanted to describe. Treating numbers in regex language is difficult - for instance, 16 through 31 is `(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01])`, i.e. "`1` followed by `6` through `9`, `2` followed by any digit, or `3` followed by `0` or `1`". You will need a similar expression to describe numbers in the `0..255` range: `(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)`.

A lot better approach would be to use [`InetAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html), which has a [`getByName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)) method for parsing the address, and lets you examine the bytes of the address with [`getAddress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAddress()) method:

```
byte[] raw = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddrString).getAddress();
boolean valid = raw[0]==172 && raw[1] >= 16 && raw[1] <= 31;
```

Comment: For completeness, the period between the number should be escaped with slashes before it.  Period without slashes means any character and would allow any character there.